# Add MarkerPopUp to MapView by clicking Button witch is in another class and problem with duplicating Layouts

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, mapview

### Q1: add MarkerPopUp by clicking Button witch is in another class

The app should import RINEX files from PC and add marker to MapView. Import is working, but I have a problem with connecting coordinates to the map. I don't know what can I do now, because a program doesn't show any error. In my example the id of MapViews are different. (Kivy file is on the bottom)

```
class FileImport(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.creator = VrsCreator()
        self.marker = MapMarkerPopup(lat=52, lon=19, source=self.creator.source_vrs)
        self.creator.ids.vrs_map.add_widget(self.marker)


class VrsCreator(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.source_pnt = 'logo/marker_pnt.png'
        self.source_vrs = 'logo/marker_vrs.png'


class VrsMap(MapView):
    pass
```

### Q2: problem with duplicating Layouts

When I try to solve first problem, I create another one. The app open second FileImport and VrsCreator in his Layouts.

#### Python file

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
import AutoVRS_functions
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarkerPopup


class FileImport(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.creator = VrsCreator()

    def selected(self, filename):
        self.ids.file_import_label.text = f'Wybrane pliki: {len(filename)}'

    def pnt_import(self, list_path):
        gdf = AutoVRS_functions.rinex_to_GeoDataFrame(list_path)
        self.ids.file_import_label.text = 'Zaimportowano wybrane pliki'

        for x in gdf[['Lat', 'Lon']].iterrows():
            print(x[1][0])
            self.creator.ids.vrs_map.add_widget(MapMarkerPopup(lat=float(x[1][0]),
                                                               lon=float(x[1][1]),
                                                               source=self.creator.source_vrs))


class VrsCreator(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.source_pnt = 'logo/marker_pnt.png'
        self.source_vrs = 'logo/marker_vrs.png'


class VrsMap(MapView):
    pass


class AutoVRSApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (44/255, 124/255, 205/255, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AutoVRSApp().run()
```

#### Kivy file

```
Template:

<Template@BoxLayout>:
    padding: 30
    spacing: 10
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        FileImport:
        VrsCreator:

<FileImport>:
    id: box_file_import
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: .4, 1
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Image:
            source: 'logo/ikona.png'

        Label:
            text: 'ver. 0.1 (demo)'
            halign: 'left'
            font_size: 14

    FileChooserIconView:
        id: file_chooser
        path: 'D:\\'
        multiselect: True
        on_selection: root.selected(file_chooser.selection)

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 0.11
        spacing: 10

        Label:
            id: file_import_label
            text: 'Wyszukaj pliki RINEX ze swojego pomiaru'
            font_size: 16
            multiline: True
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            background_color: (168/255, 208/255, 1, 1)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.background_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

        Button:
            id: RINEX_import
            text: 'Import'
            font_size: 16
            background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
            on_press: root.pnt_import(file_chooser.selection)



<VrsCreator>:
    id: vrs_creator
    spacing: 10
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 1, 0.05

        Param_desc:
            text: 'Dodatkowy czas dla VRS [minuty]'

        Input:
            text: '60'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 1, 0.05

        Param_desc:
            text: 'Powiększenie rozmiaru bufora'

        Input:
            text: '1'

    Button:
        text: 'Stwórz stacje wirtualne'
        font_size: 16
        background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
        size_hint: 1, 0.05

    VrsMap:
        id: vrs_map
        zoom: 6
        lat: 51.5
        lon: 20

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        spacing: 10

        Button:
            text: 'Pobierz dane'
            font_size: 16
            background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)

<Param_desc@Label>:
    font_size: 16
    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    background_color: (119/255, 168/255, 1, 1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos


<Input@TextInput>:
    allow_copy: True
    multiline: False
    halign: 'center'
    background_color: (182/255, 208/255, 1, 1)
    font_size: 16
```

Final effect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hjSG.png)

It's my first project in Kivy, so I hope the solution is simple 
Finally, I want to show the point using button from another class (Q1) and don't create duplicated Layouts (Q2).